# Error: Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react-app" relative to directory "/[project] frontend"

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I am following the tutorials to create a react app using create-react-app.

There were a number of dependencies that didn't get installed when loading the webpack-dev-server.

I get the following error when I try to npm run start.

What does this mean and can anyone tell me what is needed to fix it?

Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react-app" relative to directory "/[Proeject folder]/frontend"

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before `npm run start`?

Comment: I will try it but why do you have to do that?

Comment: Well if you don't have all your modules installed. That will install any missing ones.

Comment: This seemed to do it. I worked through another example and ran npm run eject. After that I would run the npm install. Seems that it works now. Then again, i have rebuilt this project numerous times but with the npm install.

Answer (score 7):

run `npm install babel-preset-react-app`